# Firebase Cloud Messaging : Parsing data from the message even when the app is terminated

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I understand that Firebase Cloud Messaging facilitates sends push notifications and data messages. I am using firebase_messaging pub from Flutter to receive the notifications in my device. The onMessage, onLaunch, and onResume callbacks are invoked only once the **notification is dismissed or clicked on**.

However, I would like to access the message received, regardless of whether the notification is dismissed or not. Is there a way to do this, regardless whether the app is in foreground, background or terminated ?

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately send your message to Broadcast receiver and here parse it

**UPDATED:**

Your should create `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
class YourBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        //some code..
    }
}
```

Then register it in `Manifest` :

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.yourApp.YourBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="YourBroadcastReceiver " />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The next and final step is in your `FirebaseMessagingService` in method `onMessageReceived` you can take ur data and send it to `YourBroadcastReceiver`:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    val messageText = remoteMessage.data[yourData]
    val intent = Intent(this, YourBroadcastReceiver ::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(messageText, messageText)
    sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

Comment: can you please give me an example ?

Comment: @vzurd yea, sure. Updated answer

Comment: Thanks Ivan. The idea of flutter was to not having to code separately for Android and iOS for the same app. However, this would only work for Android , correct? I wonder if there is any universal solution in the flutter/dart world.

Comment: @vzurd I don`t think that code will work for iOS, btw flutter is young and some code you have to separete

Comment: The FirebaseMessaging plugin is already doing that. It was a broadcast receiver to which the firebase message sends the intent from its onMessageRecieve. However, I found that it sends to a different broadcast receiver when the app is terminated. Hence it fails to invoke the dart functions that are called from the broadcast receiver. https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging